# Когда нажимаешь на вопросик, у "бизнес" нет перевода

Tags: дефект, локализация

На основном сайте и мете когда вот на этот вопросик нажимаешь, все описания ссылок переведены, а ссылка "Бизнес" - нет. Я думала, это из-за того, что она ведёт на англоязычную страницу, но "О нас" тоже ведёт на англоязычную и переведна.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]